# How can I change this range to something more dynamic?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range that I define before executing an array macro, but I have to flip the way that I am defining it. It used to be a fixed amount of columns, but now its transposed and its a fixed amount of rows.

How can I change this to express `62 rows` and columns `B to columns.count`?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Profiles")
Data = .Range("bj1", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
```

Or even taking it a step further, how could I just do columns & rows.count?

Whole script:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim Data, Last, JobFamily
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long
  Dim Dest As Range

  'Refer to the template
  Set wb = Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
  'Refer to the destination cell
  Set Dest = wb.Sheets("Sheet11").Range("B1")
  'Read in all data
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Profiles")
    Data = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With
  wb.Activate
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Process the data
  For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
    'Manager changes?
    If Data(1, i) <> Last Then
      'Skip the first
      If i > 1 Then
        'Scroll into the view
        Dest.Select
        'Save a copy
        wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
          ValidFileName(Last & ".xlsx")
      End If
      'Clear the employees
      Dest.Resize(, Columns.Count - Dest.Column).EntireColumn.ClearContents
      'Remember this manager
      Last = Data(1, i)
      'Start the next round
      j = 0
    End If
    'Write the employee data into the template
    a = 0
    For k = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
      Dest.Offset(a, j) = Data(k, i)
      a = a + 1
    Next
    'Next column
    j = j + 1
  Next
End Sub
```

getting a `subscript out of range` error on this line :

```
Dest.Offset(a, j) = Data(k, i)
```

Comment: there are many ways of doing that but the right answer depends on your actual dat layout: show it

Comment: all I need is a way to just define rows 1:62 and Column B: columns.count. Pretty straight forward, just imagine dummy data in that range

Comment: then `.Range("B1:B62")`

Comment: So, `Data = .Range("B1:B62", .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Column` ?

Comment: if you want to "define rows 1:62 and Column B", its' just `.Range("B1:B62")`, otherwise give more details about how you need to build your range up

Comment: @DisplayName will always have 62 rows in column B for that dimension, but then my columns will always fluctuate. I need to incorporate 62 rows in Column B but then up until the last column. It could be 5 columns, or it could be 300, it will always vary.

Comment: and which row will hold the _"last (not empty) column"_?

Comment: row 62. 

All I need is something like .Range("b1:b62", & columns B through last used columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on further clarifications in comments:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Profiles")
    Data = .Range("B1", .Cells(62, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With
```

while if you want to keep column B last row dynamic (and always catch last column along this latter):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Profiles")
    Data = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
End With
```

Comment: thank you, I guess I wasn't sure what you were initially asking. this worked, much apprecaited

Comment: you are welcome. see edited answer for a further step. if it solved your question you may consider marking answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: I actually just added the script at the bottom of my post, I'm getting a subscript out of range error on the line I sectioned out